# Script hangs on attempt to close modal dialog

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Have a problem when trying to close modal dialog in browser. The code is similar to the following one:

```
                1) driver.switchTo().window(1);
                2) driver.close();
                3) driver.switchTo().window(0);
```

The problem is that code execution hangs on line number 2. I believe that's because of browser (none web) dialog saying "The web page you are viewing is trying to close the window..." appearance. The script goes forward after I close the confirmation dialog manually. So, I wonder if somebody have any ideas about how to handle this issue. 
I work with IE8 browser with webdriver 2.24.1.

Comment: Did you try to put a driver.switchTo().alert() after driver.close()? I am not sure whether that will work, but its worth a try. Also, is it absolutely necessary to close the browser? If you switch to window(0) without closing window(1) Will itr affect your testing?

Comment: The code after line number 2 won't be executed if browser alert won't be closed manually (it just hangs). So, there is no difference what will be there. Yes, it's necessary to close browser window 1. The idea is to close all unnecessary windows, dialogs except the main one before starting new test.

Answer (score 0):

If A.J.'s solution:

```
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

doesn't work, I'd suggest [filing a bug](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/entry). Before that gets resolved, here's a simple workaround for you that should supress the dialog:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.onbeforeunload = function(){};");
driver.close();
```

Comment: Did manage to close modal browser pop-up with the following code (no confirmation dialog appeared):

((JavascriptExecutor)Session.getDriver()).executeScript("window.close();");

But it's still not possible to do the same with separate browser window. Confirmation dialog still appears... Same code hangs ( And it's necessary to close the confirmation dialog manually.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help! Did manage to workaround the issue by executing the following JS

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open(\"\", \"_self\");window.close();");
```